# Can I upgrade Oracle 11g 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.2 and keep my database intact?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-11g

I'm new to oracle, but I'm looking to upgrade an existing oracle database 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.2. Can anyone tell me if this will require wiping my existing database or will it remain intact?  Thanks in advance.

--Adam

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, separate the concepts of database "software installation" from the database "store of data".

11.2.0.2 has changed the upgrade mechanism. Previously you had to install the base version of the software then run an upgrade. 11.2.0.2 is installed as a separate product.

There's a walkthrough [here](http://askdba.org/weblog/2010/10/steps-to-upgrade-11201-rac-to-11202/), but the actual steps may vary depending on what your database config is (single node or RAC etc). If you are not confident, make your backup, restore to another machine and test your upgrade first. Only upgrade production when you are confident.

Answer (score 0):

Always take a backup of your database, but you should be able to run the patch to update your existing database. The Patch notes have instructions on what needs to be done (scripts that need to be run after the fact).

Comment: Always HAVE a backup of your database (whether upgrading or not) and make sure you have tested restoring it.

Comment: I'd give Gary 5 upvotes for that comment...